# How to compare date using createCriteria without the time

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-criteria

I have the following record in database

`2016-07-08 11:30:36`

I am writing the following criteria to compare the dates but I'm not getting any results back because I think it might be comparing the time part as well.

```
    Date reminderDate = new Date()
    println reminderDate //This prints: Fri Jul 08 12:45:56 EDT 2016
    def result = criteria.list {
        eq('expireDate', reminderDate)
    }
```

Comment: i dont think you can do it with equality. i think you have to search in range of 00.00.01 and 23.59.59 of same day, so `ge` and `le` together

Comment: @Apostolos I think using `between` is more elegant (see my answer)

Comment: @Donal yes correct, just wanted to exclude the equality :) or there is the option of comparing the date part of the field as jja pointed out

Answer (score 4):

You could use following:

```
Date reminderDate = new Date().clearTime() 
println reminderDate // This prints: Fri Jul 08 00:00:00 EDT 2016

def result = criteria.list { 
  ge('expireDate', reminderDate) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
Date startOfToday = new Date().clearTime()
Date startOfTomorrow = startOfToday + 1

def result = criteria.list {
    between 'expireDate', startOfToday, startOfTomorrow
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an `sqlRestriction` like:

```
sqlRestriction 'date(expire_date) = ?', [reminderDate.format('YYYY-MM-dd')]
```

Note that you have to use the database column name (which I have guessed is `expire_date`), not the HQL or GORM property name (`expireDate`). You may need to modify the date format for your database.